# How to delete data in 3 relation table in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to delete data on 3 relation table using laravel 5.7, when I am trying it on 2 relation table, it's run well, but when I'm trying it in 3 relation table, it does not work.

this is my table look like:

**table 1 : group_access**

```
|----|------------|
| id | group_name |
|----|------------|
| 67 |     test   |
|----|------------|
```

**table 2 : fa_group_access**

```
|----|-----------------|--------|
| id | group_access_id | name   |
|----|-----------------|--------|
|  1 |     67          | john   |
|----|-----------------|--------|
```

**table 3 : survey_group_access**

```
|----|-----------------|---------------|
| id | group_access_id | code_survey   |
|----|-----------------|---------------|
|  1 |     67          | SF-001        |
|----|-----------------|---------------|
```

and this is my function in the controller to delete the data:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $group = Groups::findOrFail($id);

    if($group->delete())
    {   
        Survey_group_access::where('group_access_id', $id)->get();
        FA_Group_Access::where('group_access_id', $id)->get();
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success']);    
    }   
}
```

and i got an error sql like this :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "survey_group_access_group_access_id_foreign". The conflict occurred
>   in database "aetra2", table "dbo.survey_group_access", column
>   'group_access_id'. (SQL: delete from [group_access] where [id] = 67)

How to fix this error?

Comment: show the migration files for these 3 tables

Comment: Are you trying to delete data fron table2 and table 3 when deleted from table1? This can be achieved with cascade on delete.

Comment: @InzamamIdrees i updated my model in post

Comment: @SarojShrestha yes, i want to delete data from table 1, table 2 and table 3 will delete automaticly with reference id from table 1

Comment: You just simply add **foriegn key with cascade on delete** and then simply delete the group_access row it's automatically delete related records on different other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define Relation in group_access model

```
public function fa_group_access()
{
return $this->hasMany('fa_group_access');
}

public function survey_group_access()
{
return $this->hasMany('survey_group_access');
}
```

Delete record and related:

```
$group_access = Group_access::find($id);

// delete related   
$group_access->fa_group_access()->delete();
$group_access->survey_group_access()->delete();

$group_access->delete();
```

> I don't test the code may be there is syntax error but it should be
>   some thing like this.

I hope this will help

Comment: No Problem Brother @RahmatEffendi

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a good use case for [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events). The way I'd do it is the following:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models\Administrator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Administrator\Users;

class Groups extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group_access';

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($groups) { 
            $groups->survey_group_access()->delete();
            $survey_group_access->users()->delete(); 
        });
    }

    public function fa_group_access()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FA_Group_Access::class,'group_access_id','id');
    }

    public function survey_group_access()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Survey_group_access::class,'group_access_id','id');
    }
}
```

.. and your controller method would just be:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $group = Groups::findOrFail($id);

    if($group->delete()) {  
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success']);    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with cascade on delete. You can take reference from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints.

You can update migrations:(Although my classname are just assumptions, you can get the idea, also I am assuming you are creating the database from migration and not from phpMyAdmin)

### class FAGroupAccessTable

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('fa_gropu_access', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('group_access_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreign('group_access_id ')->references('id')->on('group_access')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

### SurveyAccessGroup

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('survey_access_group', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('group_access_id ')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('code_survey');
            $table->foreign('group_access_id ')->references('id')->on('group_access')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

After doing this, whenever you try to delete with `$group_access->delete();` this two related datas will be deleted by itself.